# LINQ, simplifying expression - take while sum of taken does not exceed given value

Tags: c#, linq

Given a setup like this ..

```
class Product {
   int Cost;
   // other properties unimportant
}

var products = new List<Product> {
    new Product { Cost = 5 },
    new Product { Cost = 10 },
    new Product { Cost = 15 },
    new Product { Cost = 20 }
};

var credit = 15;
```

Assume that the list will be sorted in the given order. I wish to basically iterate over each item in the list, keep a summed value of cost, and keep getting products out as long as the **total cost** does not exceed `credit`.

I can do this with some loops and stuff, but I was wondering if there is a way to compact it into a simpler LINQ query.

Comment: The way I understand it, LINQ is going to get an interator anyway. So you might be able to write prettier code but I don't know if anything is really saved in doing so.

Comment: I would prefer a loop in this situation.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Given the samples below I have to agree with you. This is an area where LINQ doesn't feel quite right.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not "fully" linq, because it needs one extra variable, but it is the easiest I could think of:

```
int current=0;
var selection = products.TakeWhile(p => (current = current + p.Cost) <= credit);
```

Comment: The ugly thing here is that the `TakeWhile` expression has a side effect. Which IMO is against the spirit of linq.

Comment: What side effect might that be?

Comment: @Stacey: Updating `current`, which although is the *intended* effect is still a functional side-effect.

Comment: current == 30 at the end of this.  Don't use it for total cost after query iteration.

Comment: I prefer the functions used in linq to be "pure" in a functional sense. i.e. they don't mutate any state that they didn't create themselves. But of course that's just a stylistic choice and your code works and isn't too hard to understand. It's not shorter than a classical loop though.

Comment: No, it doesn't appear so. I find linq easier to read than a loop for some reason. Thanks a lot for all of the help and insight. I had never really considered the modification of an external variable to be a problem until you brought it up.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Then just write an extension method that avoids the state mutation. Please see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402393/linq-simplifying-expression-take-while-sum-of-taken-does-not-exceed-given-valu/7402438#7402438).

Comment: @Stacey: It's not a problem, per se, it just goes against the functional nature of LINQ. There is a way around it, as my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402393/linq-simplifying-expression-take-while-sum-of-taken-does-not-exceed-given-valu/7402438#7402438) shows.

Comment: **This is a very bad idea** as others have said. A sequence operator which mutates a variable is very confusing. There are better ways to do this.

Comment: @EricLippert Can you write an answer that shows the better ways to do this? I need to perform a "take while sum < x" query with LINQ to SQL.

Comment: @Shimmy: The answer which uses an aggregator illustrates the tack I would probably take.

Comment: @EricLippert Oh I see is. Anyway is there a way to achieve this in LINQ to SQL, maybe via expression trees? I can't seem to find the source code of the provider queries for LINQ to SQL. Please see [my post](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3426) on the EF repo.

Comment: @Shimmy: Unfortunately I am not at all an expert on SQL; I don't know how such a query would be constructed.

Answer (score 20):

Others have pointed out the captured variable approach, and there are arguably correct viewpoints that this approach is bad because it mutates state. Additionally, the captured variable approaches can only be iterated once, and are dangerous because a. you might forget that fact and try to iterate twice; b. the captured variable does not reflect the sum of the items taken.

To avoid these problems, just create an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeWhileAggregate<TSource, TAccumulate>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    TAccumulate seed,
    Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> func,
    Func<TAccumulate, bool> predicate
) {
    TAccumulate accumulator = seed;
    foreach (TSource item in source) {
        accumulator = func(accumulator, item);
        if (predicate(accumulator)) {
            yield return item;
        }
        else {
            yield break;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var taken = products.TakeWhileAggregate(
    0, 
    (cost, product) => cost + product.Cost,
    cost => cost <= credit
);
```

Note that NOW you can iterate twice (although be careful if your `TAccumulate` is mutable a reference type).

Comment: +1, Very nice, but you should replace `cost += product.Cost` with `cost + product.Cost` as += returns a value that you're not using (and ReSharper moans)

Comment: The latter solution is far better. Note also that you could make a version without the "seed" by simply seeding the accumulator to `default(TAccumulate)`.  I am a bit confused by your comment about mutable reference types; can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @Eric Lippert: I was thinking of a scenario where the accumulator (`func`) mutates the accumulated value thus mutating `seed`. Something like `class Foo { public int Bar { get; set; } }` Then: `Foo foo = new Foo(); var taken = products.TakeWhileAggregate(foo, (f, p) => { f.Bar+= p.Cost; return f; } f => f.Bar <= credit);`. Now `foo` is mutated on each iteration of `taken` and subsequent iterations don't produce the "same" sequence of values; that is, exactly the same problem with the captured variable approach.

Comment: Got it. Yes, that would be just as bad as the original; you couldn't do the same thing twice (or in an interleaved manner) without them interfering with each other.

Comment: @jason is there a way to achieve this in Linq to SQL, maybe via expression trees? I can't seem to find the source code of the provider queries for LINQ to SQL. Please see [my post](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3426) on the EF repo.

Comment: @Shimmy I don't think you can achieve this in SQL, so there would be no point in trying it in LINQ to SQL. If I take T-SQL into account, using `OVER` with `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` could have yielded the result you wanted, but unfortunatelly, you cannot use `OVER` in the `WHERE` clause, unless your query inside another one. But that would not be lazy.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you want a solution without an external variable

```
var indexQuery = products.Select((x,index) => new { Obj = x, Index = index });

var query = from p in indexQuery 
            let RunningTotal = indexQuery.Where(x => x.Index <= p.Index)
                                         .Sum(x => x.Obj.Cost)
            where credit >= RunningTotal
            select p.Obj;
```

Comment: @Corey: in all fairness he never said it was the most efficient way of doing it. If you can find a more efficient way to do it without an external variable I'd be very interested though.

Comment: @Chris, IMO the nicest way of doing it is using the "Scan" LINQ operator from the Reactive framework. For the sake of simplicity, I'll post code below using my own version of Scan.

Comment: @Corey: Oooh, I'm very interested then. I've been looking at the Reactive Framework in the last few days so exampels of its use would be great. :)

Answer (score 1):

ok, re my comment above in @Aducci's answer, here's a version using Scan

```
      var result=products.Scan(new {Product=(Product)null, RunningSum=0},
        (self, next) => new {Product=next, RunningSum=self.RunningSum+next.Cost})
        .Where(x=>x.RunningSum<=credit)
        .Select(x => x.Product);
```

And this is my implementation of Scan (which I assume is similar to what's in the Rx Framework, but I haven't checked)

```
    public static IEnumerable<TAccumulate> Scan<TSource, TAccumulate>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
      TAccumulate seed, Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> accumulator) {

      foreach(var item in source) {
        seed=accumulator(seed, item);
        yield return seed;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a captured variable to track the amount taken so far.

```
int sum = 0;

IEnumerable<Product> query = products.TakeWhile(p =>
{
  bool canAfford = (sum + p.Cost) <= credit;
  sum = canAfford ? sum + p.Cost : sum;
  return canAfford;
});
```