# How to split a string on the 3rd occurence of a char C#

Tags: c#

I was wondering is there a way to split a string on the 3rd occurence of a char? When splitting previously i was using:

```
line.Substring(line.LastIndexOf(']') +1);
```

I hadn't realised some of my strings had extra square brackets than others so ideally i need to split on the 3rd occurence of ']' as this is the same position on every string.

Input: [Wed Dec 17 14:40:28 2014] [error] [client 143.117.101.166] File does not exist:

Output:

[Wed Dec 17 14:40:28 2014] [error] [client 143.117.101.166]

File does not exist:

Comment: Can you provide an input and expected output ?

Comment: The question has been edited with input and expected output

Comment: Here's a [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2641383/2919731) that has a `AllIndesOff()` method. You could use that.

Comment: There is no such feature *(built-in)* in c#. You'll have to implement your own custom method to find the *N-th* occurance of passed char and n.

Comment: I don't know what your goal is, but it looks like regex's might be a good way to select the desired parts of that string.

Comment: If this position is constant as you mention so why don't you use **Substring(0, 60)** (60 is for example input)

Comment: @Klaudiuszbryjamus I'm already splitting the date/time and IP into elements in an array as they are surrounded by square brackets, the string after, in this case 'file does not exist' isn't enclosed in brackets and therefore splitting it by 3rd occurence of ']' seemed a viable way to split the rest of the string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to split the string first then take the index of the 3rd ]

```
line.Substring(line.IndexOf(line.Split(']')[3]));
```

or more easy as you said the 3rd index of ] is the same, put it fixed

```
line.Substring(59);
```

Comment: This answer done exactly what i wanted with minimal code. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

This input can be matched with a regular expression:

```
\[[^\]]*\]\s*\[[^\]]*\]\s*\[[^\]]*\]
```

This looks scary because of escape sequences, but the structure is very straightforward: it matches three occurrences of `[` + zero or more non-`]` + `]`, separated by zero or more spaces.

```
var s = "[Wed Dec 17 14:40:28 2014] [error] [client 143.117.101.166] File does not exist:";
var r = new Regex(@"(\[[^\]]*\]\s*\[[^\]]*\]\s*\[[^\]]*\])(.*)$");
var m = r.Match(s);
if (m.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine("Prefix: {0}", m.Groups[1]);
    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", m.Groups[2]);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/TAFu2n)

Comment: I'm confusing myself when trying to implement this code, can i give you a bit of background and then see if i can understand it a bit more?

Comment: The line of code supplied as the example is only one line from a .txt file, error log in this case. Within a while loop i'm reading in each line (every line has the exact same format up to the end of the IP i.e the 3rd occurence of the ']') and splitting it up and inserting into an array. So at the moment i have it splitting with squared brackets which is okay, but for the error message i need it to split on 3rd occurence of ']' and take the rest of the string. Could you help me understand how to implement?

Comment: @Michael I modified regex to match the rest of the line, and capture it in group #2. See edit.

Answer (score 2):

Use Regex to solve the problem,this will capture content with `[]`

```
string input = " [Wed Dec 17 14:40:28 2014] [error] [client 143.117.101.166] File does not exist";
var regex = new Regex("\\[(.*?)\\]");
var matches = regex.Matches(input);
foreach (var match in matches) // e.g. you can loop through your matches like this
{
   //yourmatch
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a simple Split in this case:

```
var items = line.Split(new[]{']','['},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
if (items.Count > 3) { 
   /* use items[2], or whatever you need... */ 
}
```

Because the first items are always bracketted and the same format, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as far as I know, C# does not have an inbuilt function for what you seek. Using Regular Expressions is an alternative you could use.

If not, there's another way in which you could get your desired outcome, but that will work only for these particular set of strings. But again, `REGEX` too has the same problem.

In your string, if you observe the first two occurrences of `]` are always followed by `[`

What I am suggesting is, whenever you find the index of `]` you could just check the next character in the string, and if the next character is not `[` only then you have to split.

There are infinite number of ways to solve your problem, select the one which makes your code the most modular.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a common task you can create an extension method that gives you all the positions where the character you want is, something like:

```
static class ExtMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> IndexesOf(this string str, char c)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            if (str[i] == c)
            yield return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can get the position of the third `]` with something like:

```
int thirdPos = str.IndexesOf(']').Take(3).Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ:

```
string input = "[Wed Dec 17 14:40:28 2014] [error] [client 143.117.101.166] File does not exist:";

var result = input.Select((ch, ind) => new { ch, ind }).Where(x => x.ch == ']').Skip(2).FirstOrDefault();

string output = input.Substring(result.ind + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility using Linq:

(Take chars from the string until you've seen three square close brackets, then send the output back to the String constructor as an array.)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string test = "[Wed Dec 17 14:40:28 2014] [error] [client 143.117.101.166] File does not exist:";

    var result = SplitOnChar(test, ']', 3);

    Debug.WriteLine(result.Item1);
    Debug.WriteLine(result.Item2);
}

static Tuple<string, string> SplitOnChar(string input, char c, int occurrence)
{
    int charCount = 0;
    string firstPart = new String(input.TakeWhile(x => (x == ']' ? charCount++ : charCount) < 3).ToArray());
    string lastPart = input.Substring(firstPart.Length);
    return Tuple.Create(firstPart, lastPart);
}
```

Credit goes to this answer for the technique: [LINQ, simplifying expression - take while sum of taken does not exceed given value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402393/linq-simplifying-expression-take-while-sum-of-taken-does-not-exceed-given-val)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
public static class SplitExtension
{
    public static string[] Split(this string self, char separator, int occurrence)
    {
        return self.Split(new string(separator, 1), occurrence);
    }

    public static string[] Split(this string self, string separator, int occurrence)
    {
        string[] chunks = self.Split(new[] { separator }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        string firstPart = string.Join(separator, chunks.Take(occurrence)) + separator;
        string secondPart = string.Join(separator, chunks.Skip(occurrence));
        return new string[] { firstPart, secondPart };
    }
}
```

... and then use it like this:

```
string input = "[Wed Dec 17 14:40:28 2014] [error] [client 143.117.101.166] File does not exist";
string[] output = input.Split(']', 3);

// output[0] = "[Wed Dec 17 14:40:28 2014] [error] [client 143.117.101.166]";
// output[1] = " File does not exist";
```