# Get all items in list until cumulative sum reaches a limit value

Tags: c#, aggregate-functions, generic-list, cumulative-sum

I've a `List<Tuple<DateTime, double>>`. This list is guarantee sorted by DateTime. Now I want to get all items which are included in the cumulative sum until a limit value is reached. What is the most elegant way to do this?

```
DateTime             | double     | c. sum   | Limit | in result list?
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-10-28 07:51:10  | 0.3        | 0.3      | 5     | yes
2019-10-28 07:51:11  | 0.2        | 0.5      | 5     | yes
2019-10-28 07:51:12  | 0.7        | 1.2      | 5     | yes
2019-10-28 07:51:13  | 0.67       | 1.87     | 5     | yes
2019-10-28 07:51:14  | 1.0        | 2.87     | 5     | yes
2019-10-28 07:51:15  | 0.1        | 2.97     | 5     | yes
2019-10-28 07:51:16  | 0.9        | 3.87     | 5     | yes
2019-10-28 07:51:17  | 0.32       | 4.19     | 5     | yes
2019-10-28 07:51:18  | 0.21       | 4.40     | 5     | yes
2019-10-28 07:51:19  | 0.25       | 4.65     | 5     | yes
2019-10-28 07:51:20  | 0.6        | 5.25     | 5     | yes (more values don't need to be calculated, limit is reached)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-10-28 07:51:21  | 0.4        | 5.65     | 5     | no
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: and [LINQ, simplifying expression - take while sum of taken does not exceed given value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402393/linq-simplifying-expression-take-while-sum-of-taken-does-not-exceed-given-val)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would do something like this:

```
var list = new List<Tuple<DateTime, double>>
{
    ....
};

var sum = 0d;
var limit = 10d;

var result = list.TakeWhile(x => (sum += x.Item2) < limit).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [`TakeWhile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile?view=netframework-4.8) may be a good candidate here.

```
var list = new []{1,2,3,4};

var sum1 = 0;
var triggerValue = 6;
var afterSumReached = list.TakeWhile( x => { sum1 += x; return sum1 <= triggerValue; } );
// first 3 elements.
```

or

```
var sum2 = 0;
var beforeSumReached = list.TakeWhile( x => { 
    if( sum2 + x >= triggerValue) return false;
    sum2+=x; 
    return true;
});
// first 2 elements
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write an extension method like below:

```
public static class ListTupleExtension
{
    public static List<Tuple<DateTime, double>> CumulativeSum(this List<Tuple<DateTime, double>> sequence, double limit)
    {
        List<Tuple<DateTime, double>> result = new List<Tuple<DateTime, double>>();
        double sum = 0;
        foreach(var item in sequence)
        {
            if (sum <= limit)
            {
                sum += item.Item2;
            }

            result.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, double>(item.Item1, sum));
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

then call it on the list as

```
list = list.CumulativeSum(limit);
```

Check [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/v89Xy2) dotnetfiddle which demonstrates the usage.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I corrected two litte mistakes in the implementation. In the Fiddler example these can also be seen (two much items in result, the original value of the row is also important).